# Sum for unique combinations of variables in a data table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table with the following format representing relations strength between countries for many categories of relations:

```
Country1    Country2     Value     Category
A           A            4         1
A           B            2         1
A           C            9         1
B           A            3         2
B           D            4         1
C           A            2         2
D           C            7         2
...
```

Now I would like to sum all mutual relations (e.g. A-B and B-A; D-C and C-D, etc...) for each category (A-B and B-A needs to be "merged").

What could be a concise and "very R" solution to do it? Is there any existing function that could do this?

For now, I've set a key with both "Country1" and "Country2" columns but didn't find what I could do next for matching corresponding rows..

Thanks for any clue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `pmin` and `pmax`..

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.6
dt = fread("Country1    Country2     Value     Category
A           A            4         1
A           B            2         1
A           C            9         1
B           A            3         2
B           D            4         1
C           A            2         2
D           C            7         2")
dt[, .(total = sum(Value)), 
     by=.(Country1 = pmin(Country1, Country2), 
          Country2 = pmax(Country1, Country2))]
#    Country1 Country2 total
# 1:        A        A     4
# 2:        A        B     5
# 3:        A        C    11
# 4:        B        D     4
# 5:        C        D     7
```

If you want this within `Category`, just add it as well to `by`.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

How you "sum all mutual bipartite relations" depends on what you want to do.

To count the number of relations in each category:

```
x[, .N, by=Category]
```

To sum up the `value` for all relationships in each category:

```
x[, sum(Value), by=Category]
```

or this for prettier output:

```
x[, list(TotalValue = sum(Value)), by=Category]
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe the question was not clear enough.. I need to sum "value" for all unique combination of fromCountry-toCountry relations for each category..

Comment: In fact, the answer could be something similar to dt[, sum(value), by = c(cat, "unique_combination_of_countries")]

Comment: @Marc, see Arun's answer then.

Answer (score 0):

```
# x = your data as data.table
x[,  rel :=paste(fromCountry, toCountry, sep = "-")]
x[, .(sums = sum(Value)), by = rel]

# if fromCountry - toCountry is considered to be bidirectional, then make sets:

library(Kmisc)
x[, sets := Kmisc::str_sort(rel)]
x[, .(sum = sum(Value)), by = sets]
```

Comment: they aren't; in your table A-B = 2 and B-A = 3.

Comment: Yes, I need to merge both so that the result will be A-B = 5 and B-A will be removed..